# InstallShield 2019 R3 - IsCmdBld Ignores MSI Command-Line Arguments

Tags: installshield

I am using InstallShield 2019 R3

I have specified some arguments in the "MSI Command-Line Arguments" field under Releases -> Setup.exe.

When I build directly from InstallShield 2019 Application, these Arguments are packaged into the Setup.exe file.

When I build using IsCmdBld the arguments that I have specified are ignored and are not added to the setup.ini file under [StartUp]CmdLine=

Is there a specific switch I need to use to have these included when using IsCmdBld or maybe I am doing something wrong?

I have tried different package types (Network Install, Web etc) and they all seem to have the same issue.  I have also posted on the Flexera Community, but so far not had any responses!

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Odds are good you haven't told it which product configuration and release to build (`-a` and `-r` IIRC), and for some reason it's choosing to create a new one that doesn't have your setting's value.

Comment: Awesome! I had the -a but not the -r and the -a was also wrong...Solve it, thanks for your help :) I spent too many hours trying to sort it out.